# Создание Android приложений. Sockets

Tags: android, java, сокет

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема использования сокета.
Вот отдельный от проекта файл Client.java, который служит для проверки соединения в консольном режиме:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.*;


public class Client {
    static AffableThread mSecondThread;
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
     mSecondThread = new AffableThread();
     mSecondThread.start();
}
}
class AffableThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Абракадабра");
        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
            }catch(UnknownHostException e){}catch(IOException e){}
        System.out.println("Подключайся любезнейший!");
    }
}
```

Работает на ура, подключается к серверу без проблем.
Но стоит мне распихать элементы этого кода по моему основному коду, то выдает ошибкy:

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: и какую же ошибку выдаёт? Полный stack trace сюда

Comment: Эээ... Мы тут так не играем. Мы играем вот как: задаём вопрос, получаем ответ, принимаем его. Задающий получает ответ, отвечающий получает 15 маны за принятый ответ. Если потом возникает ещё вопрос, то новый создают. А не так: создаю вопрос, получаю ответ, изменяю вопрос. Не надо так! По что меня 15-ти маны лишили и логику работы форума поломали?.. =(

Comment: Да ладно вам, я не знаю, как тут подарить 15 маны вам)) 
Но суть вопроса так и не решена. Я уже не использую другой класс файл, я уже пытаюсь в одном классе все сделать, что все-равно тупо безуспешно.
Сказали создать новый поток - покопал в инете - вроде как создал. Вот только толку от него, если все-равно не работает
P.S. Сижу и задумался над вашим 2-м пунктом в ответе и теперь думаю. Каким же образом я смогу создать еще потоки, и тем более вызвать их, если мне они нужны в потоке onCreate? Как все сложно.
В общем, не получается и все. Запутался со всем.

Comment: Таки мана как раз мне за нажатую галочку у ответа начисляют, так что всё путём. И onCreate() это не поток, а часть жизненного цикла активити или фрагмента. Вам надо про это почитать и про способы общения разных потоков меж собой в андроиде. А **NullPointerException** говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь использовать какую-то неинициализированную переменную где-то. Оформите свой код кратко в отдельный вопрос и посмотрите, на какой конкретно строчке исключение падает.

Comment: Ну и ещё: ни разу не видел, где и зачем в андроиде нужен **main**. Проще конструктором пользоваться. Но это так, чисто мои эстетические предпочтения)

Comment: @VladEv1L поучите лучше основы явы. А то объяснять фундаментальные мелочи...

Comment: @argamidon Самоучка слез с C#, php. На яве писал игровой сервер, но со стороны клиента ничего не знаю. Основы мне не помогут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без логов ошибки сложно сказать, но вот мои предположения:

1. Нет разрешения в манифесте на интернет
2. Работа с сетью идёт в основном потоке (т.е. в onCreate() активити или фрагмента). Так с определённой версии андроида низзя. Надо делать в отдельном потоке. Например в Service или AsynkTask.

Если всё же использовать Service, то надо про него почитать [доки](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html).

И делать как-то так:

Создаём класс, расширяющий класс **android.app.Service**:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
//вот тут можно работать с сетью без проблем.
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Теперь его надо прописать в манифесте:

```
<service
        android:name="ВАШ_ПАКЕТ.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/service_name" />
```

И наконец, теперь можно вызвать всё это из активити:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
this.startService(intent);
```

Comment: @VladEv1L, логи можно добавить в вопрос. Но и так понятно, что у вас 2-ой вариант из моего ответа. **NetworkOnMainThreadException** как раз об этом говорит. Работайте с сетью **НЕ** в основном потоке.

Comment: один из немногочисленных плюсов андроида - отслеживание сети в основном потоке. :)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, но поэтому ранее я создал отдельный класс CONservice.java:
package service;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.*;
public class CONservice {
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
  try{
         Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
         }catch(UnknownHostException e){}catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
Вопрос - как его реализовать так, что бы я мог его вызвать в нужном месте в активити?

Comment: @argamidon, если честно, то я не понял, что вы хотите этим сказать)

Comment: @VladEv1L выложи нормально код в первый пост.
 ничерта не видно же

Comment: Выложил первый вариант... Слушайте, то есть в главном классе активити (экран) я не могу вызвать никаким образом подключение к серверу?

Comment: Можешь. создай второй поток из главной активити.

Comment: @VladEv1L, можно по разному. Если через сервис - см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: Сервис работает в том же ui потоке =) , так что надо запускать отдельный поток. Но проблема не в этом.. проблема относится к листингу, я так понял, причем тут андроид?! =) 

Comment: @TheElizarov, сам вопрос был изначально про падение приложения при пользовании сетью в onCreate() активити)